# Find max value in for loop range - Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I've been working on a small program that takes the input of two numbers and gives the greatest common divisor.  I have managed to get the program to at least print out all common divisors until the greatest number is reached, but all I need to print is the max value.  Unfortunately, I can't get seem to get this to work.  I've tried passing i though max() but was received an error that ''int' objects are not iterable''. Thus I am wondering if anyone could help me find a solution that will allow me to print only the max value as opposed to all values without having to employ much more complex coding methods.  Here is the code

```
def great_divisor():
m = int(raw_input("Choose a number"))
n = int(raw_input("Choose another number"))
#lowest number assigned to d
if m > n:
    d = n
else:
    d = m

for i in range(1, d + 1):

    if (n%i == 0 and m%i == 0):
        print(max(i))
return
```

Comment: `d = min(m,n)` should replace your `if...else`, for one thing.

Comment: Why not just use `gcd` from the `fractions` module? Related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175131/code-for-greatest-common-divisor-in-python). `gcd` is in the `math` module if you are using 3.3

Comment: the point of the exercise isn't calculating gcd, but rather working with for loops.  I would have if the point was to calculate that efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `range(d, 0, -1)` and just return the first divisor you find. No need to use `max`.

Comment: thanks that managed to reverse the numbers, now just to figure out how to get it to only return one divisor

Comment: Just do `if (n%i == 0 and m%i == 0): return i`

Answer (score 0):

Max can only be applied to an iterable, a list for example.

You can add all the common divisor in a list and get the max.

```
for i in range(1, d + 1):
    if (n%i == 0 and m%i == 0):
        divisors.append(i)
print(max(divisors))
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can declare a max_divisor variable and chek if i is greater than max_divisor.

Comment: did you mean .add or .append? I had to use append to get the same effect. I'm running 2.7 though...

Comment: Yes sorry, it is .append()

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
maxn = 0
for i in range(1, d + 1):

    if (n%i == 0 and m%i == 0):
        maxn = i

return maxn
```

Comment: hmm, not working.  Now the program just returns none as opposed to a number