# Source code for str.split?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

I would like to see how `str.split()` is implemented in Python  Here's what I tried:

```
> inspect.getsource(str.split)

TypeError: <method 'split' of 'str' objects> is not a module, 
class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

Copying the other example on StackOverflow has not work: [Code for Greatest Common Divisor in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175131/code-for-greatest-common-divisor-in-python)

Comment: It's a builtin method, implemented in compiled code.  You'd have to search the Python source repository.

Comment: E.g. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l10208

Comment: @jonrsharpe that C++ code looks very complicated -- tells me a lot.  Thanks!

Comment: CPython is written in [tag:c]!

Comment: The actual algorithms for splitting strings are located in `stringlib/split.h`: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/stringlib/split.h

Answer (score 12):

`inspect.getsource(str.split)` is not written to handle code written in the implementation language (`C` here). `str.split` is *builtin*, i.e written in `C`.

The source code for the implementation of `str.split` is broken up in two parts based on if a `sep` argument is supplied.

The first function, for when no `sep` argument is supplied and split removes white space characters, is [`split_whitespace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/459cd61399f589caccae1c0fa2138ebcaaa63ea6/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L54). How it is implemented is pretty straight-forward; the main bulk is located in the `while` loop that removes leading whitespace, searches the remaining string characters if any white space exists and splits on it. I've added some comments for illustrating this:

```c
i = j = 0;
while (maxcount-- > 0) {
    /* Increment counter past all leading whitespace in 
       the string. */
    while (i < str_len && STRINGLIB_ISSPACE(str[i]))
        i++;
    /* if string only contains whitespace, break. */
    if (i == str_len) break;

    /* After leading white space, increment counter 
       while the character is not a whitespace. 
       If this ends before i == str_len, it points to 
       a white space character. */
    j = i; i++;
    while (i < str_len && !STRINGLIB_ISSPACE(str[i]))
        i++;
#ifndef STRINGLIB_MUTABLE
    /* Case where no split should be done, return the string. */
    if (j == 0 && i == str_len && STRINGLIB_CHECK_EXACT(str_obj)) {
        /* No whitespace in str_obj, so just use it as list[0] */
        Py_INCREF(str_obj);
        PyList_SET_ITEM(list, 0, (PyObject *)str_obj);
        count++;
        break;
    }
#endif
    /* Make the split based on the incremented counters. */
    SPLIT_ADD(str, j, i);
}
```

Similarly, [`split_char`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/459cd61399f589caccae1c0fa2138ebcaaa63ea6/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L102) is the case where a character is supplied as `sep`. Its implementation is again pretty straight-forward, examine it a bit after seeing `split_whitespace`; you won't find it too difficult.

There's also the [`split` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/459cd61399f589caccae1c0fa2138ebcaaa63ea6/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L145) for handling cases where the separator is more than one characters long. This is implemented by searching for the characters in the string and splitting accordingly.