# How does .split() work? - Python

Tags: python, string, split

In the following examples, I am splitting an empty string by a space. However, in the first example I explicitly used a space and in the second example, I didn't. My understanding was that `.split()` and `.split(' ')` were equivalent.

Why do these two examples give different outputs?

```
In [1]: "".split(' ')
Out[1]: ['']

In [2]: "".split()
Out[2]: []
```

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split? It's explained there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Source code for str.split?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332743/source-code-for-str-split)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) -

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

Sep is the separator. What it says is if we don't pass anything to split, **whitespaces** are considered as separators, it will **apply a different algorithm** to split strings and will return us a `[]` but since **you passed a sep**, it will **not apply this algorithm**