# Equals support for self-built Fraction class

Tags: python, class, operators

```
class Fraction:
    """Class for performing fraction arithmetic.
    Each Fraction has two attributes: a numerator, n and a deconominator, d.
    Both must be integer and the deonominator cannot be zero."""

    def __init__(self,n,d):
        """Performs error checking and standardises to ensure denominator is 
positive"""
        if type(n)!=int or type(d)!=int:
            raise TypeError("n and d must be integers")
        if d==0:
            raise ValueError("d must be positive")
        elif d<0:
            self.n = -n
            self.d = -d
        else:
            self.n = n
            self.d = d

    def __str__(self):
        """Gives string representation of Fraction (so we can use print)"""
        return(str(self.n) + "/" + str(self.d))

    def __add__(self, otherFrac):
        """Produces new Fraction for the sum of two Fractions"""
        newN = self.n*otherFrac.d + self.d*otherFrac.n
        newD = self.d*otherFrac.d
        newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
        return(newFrac)

    def __sub__(self, otherFrac):
        """Produces new Fraction for the difference between two Fractions"""        
        newN = self.n*otherFrac.d - self.d*otherFrac.n
        newD = self.d*otherFrac.d
        newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
        return(newFrac)

    def __mul__(self, otherFrac):
        """Produces new Fraction for the product of two Fractions"""        
        newN = self.n*otherFrac.n
        newD = self.d*otherFrac.d
        newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
        return(newFrac)

    def __truediv__(self, otherFrac):
        """Produces new Fraction for the quotient of two Fractions"""        
        newN = self.n*otherFrac.d
        newD = self.d*otherFrac.n
        newFrac = Fraction(newN, newD)
        return(newFrac)
```

As code showed above, how can I print

```
Fraction(1,3) == Fraction(2,6)
```

As example:

```
Fraction(1,2) + Fraction(1,3)
Fraction(1,2) - Fraction(1,3)
Fraction(1,2) * Fraction(1,3)
Fraction(1,2) / Fraction(1,3)
```

They are all work for calculation every time. And when I try to print fraction(1,3) == fraction(2,6), it come out as `False`. How can I let it calculate as `True`?

How can I do it without using `import fraction`.

Comment: You need to implement `__eq__` . This is the method that decides if two objects are equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return  self.n*other.d == self.d*other.n
```

As pointed out in the comments, there is no need to implement the `__ne__`.

**EDIT:** As requested in the comments to this answer, here is a method for simplifying fractions.

The simplification of fraction implies dividing both numbers by the greatest common divisor. As posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175131/code-for-greatest-common-divisor-in-python) the code is rather simple

```
# return the simplified version of a fraction
def simplified(self):
    # calculate the greatest common divisor
    a = self.n
    b = self.d
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    # a is the gcd
    return Fraction(self.n/a, self.d/a)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: The last comment is incorrect. If there's no `__ne__` method it will negate the result of `__eq__`: "By default, `__ne__()` delegates to `__eq__()` and inverts the result unless it is `NotImplemented`." (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Comment: @ko-ko As an aside, you are reporting `("d must be positive")` where you actually mean `("d must be non-zero")`

Comment: Thank you @MSeifert ! I was not aware of that

Comment: Not sure about the first comment, I guess that was directed at the questioner?

Comment: Shoud it not be `return  self.n*other.d == self.d*other.n`?

Comment: You are right, @MarkBeilfuss . Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Very clever way to solve this! +1. Personally I would "simplify" the fractions during `__init__` because it's just more convenient for all operations but your approach definetly works.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, no need to make things difficult when it is simple.

Answer (score 2):

The [data model](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) specifies `__eq__` as method that implements `==` checks.

A very simple implementation of `__eq__` would be:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.n == other.n and self.d == other.d
```

It would work for `Fraction(1, 2) == Fraction(1, 2)` but it wouldn't work for `Fraction(1, 2) == Fraction(2, 4)`.

You would need modify the contents of the `__eq__` method so it allows even to compare multiples.

Answer (score 1):

In python to get custom behavior for the == operator you must provide an implementation for the method `__eq__`. If you don't override it the default behavior is to check if the objects are really the same object, which in this case they are not.