# python - Return numbers that share no common factors

Tags: python

Problem is as follows:

> Create a function that takes 2 inputs, a number `n` and a list `lst`.
>   The function should return a list of all the numbers in `lst` that
>   share no common factors with `n` (other than 1). n and all numbers in
>   `lst` will be positive integers greater than or equal to 0.

My attempt

```
def no_common_factors (n, lst):

    def uf(n):  #get a set of factors
        factors = []
        i = 2
        while n > 1: 
            if n % i == 0: 
                factors += [i]
                n = n / i
            else: 
                i += 1
        return set(factors)

    factors_n = uf(n)
    no_common = []

    for i in range(0, len(lst)): 
        factors_i = uf(i)
        if factors_n.isdisjoint(factors_i): 
            no_common += [lst[i]]
        else: 
            continue

    return no_common
```

doesn't work:

```
In [41]: no_common_factors(15, [72,27,32,61,77,11,40])
Out[41]: [72, 27, 32, 77]
```

when it should return [32, 61, 77, 11].

I stare at it but can't see what I'm doing wrong, it's supposed to be really simple. Please help!

Comment: You are checking the factors of the iteration variable `i` instead of the actual number. Either do `uf(lst[i])` or better iterate over the numbers themselves `for x in lst:`

Comment: Is that a common thing to have a function within a function? It looks strange to me.

Comment: @Felk, thank you very much!

Comment: @offeltoffel, that's the best I could come up with, but I think it's relatively common. :)

Comment: You can move the `def uf(n)` function to the top and it will still work and look a bit nicer. Now that you have your desired answer, this is only maculature ;)

Comment: @offeltoffel, true, I should reduce the bulk... :D  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bug is in the `factors_i` calculation.

Replace:

```
factors_i = uf(i)
```

By:

```
factors_i = uf(lst[i])
```

By the way, you can simplify your code:

```
def no_common_factors(n, lst):
    factors_n = uf(n)
    no_common = []

    for integer in lst:
        factors_i = uf(integer)
        if factors_n.isdisjoint(factors_i):
            no_common.append(integer)

    return no_common
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't see that.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it using `math.gcd` which returns the greatest common divisor of two numbers:

```
import math

def no_shared_factors(num, items):
    return [item for item in items if math.gcd(item, num) == 1]
```

which outputs the correct result:

```
>>> no_shared_factors(15, [72, 27, 32, 61, 77, 11, 40])
[32, 61, 77, 11]
```

If `math.gcd` is too much of a black box, you could write your own implementation or peek the `math` code (see [Code for Greatest Common Divisor in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175131/code-for-greatest-common-divisor-in-python)):

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """
    Calculate the Greatest Common Divisor of a and b.

    Unless b==0, the result will have the same sign as b (so that when
    b is divided by it, the result comes out positive).
    """
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a
```

Take a look at the GCD page on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) for many more alternative algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's a waaay more elegant solution.