# How to find the highest common factor of a pair of numbers?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
num1= int(input('Enter the first number: '))
num2= int(input('Enter the second number: '))

def hcf(num1,num2):
    if num2==0:
        return num1
    else:
        return hcf(num2, num1%num2)
    print('The highest common factor', (hcf))

hcf(num1, num2)
```

It is not printing like I thought it would. I need to find the highest common factor.

Comment: How is that different than [gcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175131/code-for-greatest-common-divisor-in-python)?

Answer (score 2):

In both branch, the `if` and the `else` you use `return`, so no code is executed after that, the print is `unreachable`. You may store the result of the method (given by the `return`) then print it

```
def hcf(num1,num2):
    if num2==0:
        return num1
    else:
        return hcf(num2, num1%num2)

res = hcf(num1, num2)    
print('The highest common factor is', res)
```

---

And so you know, your ***highest common factor*** is generally known as ***greatest common divisor*** so called [**GCD**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) and is present in the package `math` in python

```
from math import gcd
res = gcd(num1, num2)
print('The greatest common divisor is', res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the "greatest common divisor" by "highest common factor", you can use `math.gcd`:

```
from math import gcd

a = int(input("Number 1: "))
b = int(input("Number 2: "))
print("Greatest common divisor:", gcd(a, b))
```

Comment: He can use many things, but that doesn't helkp him with his own that he's asking about...