# How to simplify a fraction in Python?

Tags: python, function, fractions, simplify

still learning Python so any help is welcome.
I have written a funtion to get a fraction, but more often than not the fraction can be simplified. My code does not do this yet. Any ideas how to simplify the fraction without using any `import` functions?
code:

```
def add_frac(n1, d1, n2, d2):
    frac = (((n1 * d1) + (n2 * d2)), (d1 * d2))
    return frac
```

example:
`add_frac(1, 2, 1, 4)` gives `(6, 8)` in stead of `(3, 4)`

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

A pretty naive approach to get you started, you can add some checks to make it more efficient.

```
def simplify_frac(n, d):
    i = 2
    while i < min(n, d) + 1:
        if n % i == 0 and d % i == 0:
            n = n // i
            d = d // i
        else:
            i += 1
    return n, d

# Some examples 
In [105]: simplify_frac(2, 4)
Out[105]: (1, 2)

In [106]: simplify_frac(16, 36)
Out[106]: (4, 9)

In [107]: simplify_frac(7, 3)
Out[107]: (7, 3)

In [108]: simplify_frac(10, 1)
Out[108]: (10, 1)

In [109]: simplify_frac(1, 10)
Out[109]: (1, 10)

In [110]: simplify_frac(102, 10)
Out[110]: (51, 5)

In [111]: simplify_frac(110, 10)
Out[111]: (11, 1)
```

We use a modulo operator `%` to check the remainder from integer division by `i`, if both `n and d` have a remainder of `0` we know `i` divides them.

Answer (score 1):

The naive form of adding two fractions returns *a* correct answer, just not the most *reduced* correct answer. For that, you need to divide the numerator and denominator of the result by the greatest common denominator (GCD) of the original denominators. In this case, the GCD of 2 and 4 is 2, so dividing 6 and 8 by 2 gives the desired answer `(3,4)`

`math.gcd` can be used:

```
from math import gcd


def add_frac(n1, d1, n2, d2):
    x = gcd(d1, d2)
    frac = (((n1 * d2) + (n2 * d1)) / x, (d1 * d2) / x)
    return frac
```

though it sounds like you are expected to define your own implementation of `gcd`.

Comment: He knows `6/8` can be simplified to `3/4`. His question is about the algorithm how to achieve that. How do you get the GCD of the original denominators? It also seems like a homework which is why he is asking not to use imported functions.

Comment: There are plenty of resources for implementing the GCD algorithm, and if that's the necessary part of the solution, then it's a separate question (and one that's too broad without an initial attempt to write it).

Comment: I would also suggest making a function that normalizes fractions, otherwise this code will be duplicated in every arithmetic operation on fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a recursive implementation of gcd, using [Euclid Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm); it also works on negative numbers :

```
def mygcd(a, b) :
    return gcd_rec(abs(a), abs(b))

def gcd_rec(a,b) :
    if a*b == 0 : return a+b
    if a <= b : return gcd_rec(a, b % a)
    return gcd_rec(a % b, b)

def add_frac(n1, d1, n2, d2):
    n = n1*d2 + n2*d1
    d = d1*d2
    g = mygcd(n, d)
    return n//g, d//g
```

Comment: I get `(13, 4)` for `add_frac(1,1,3,4)` (should be `(7,4)`).  Maybe you need to catch a special case?

Comment: This works great, but it does not work when you could simplify it twice. for example (1, 2, 1, 6). It gives (4, 6), but should give (2, 3). Any way to get this?

Comment: in fact, I've computed gcd before summing; fixed

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answers, if you cannot import any other libraries, here's is the implementation of fractions.gcd for python 2.7 (copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175154/10155740)

```
>>> print inspect.getsource(gcd)
def gcd(a, b):
    """Calculate the Greatest Common Divisor of a and b.

    Unless b==0, the result will have the same sign as b (so that when
    b is divided by it, the result comes out positive).
    """
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
```

so if you'd incorporate this in your code, you should get something like:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a

def add_frac(n1, d1, n2, d2):
    frac = (((n1 * d1) + (n2 * d2)), (d1 * d2))
    return tuple(i//gcd(*frac) for i in frac)

print(add_frac(1,2,1,4))
# OUTPUT: (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide it by GCD.

```
import math
def add_frac(n1, d1, n2, d2):
    nume = (n1 * d1) + (n2 * d2)
    deno = d1 * d2
    gcd = math.gcd(nume,deno)
    nume /= gcd
    deno /= gcd
    return (nume,deno)

>>> add_frac(1,2,1,4)
>>> (3.0, 4.0)
```