# solved infinite recursion and looping using break and return statements

Tags: python, algorithm

```
#a=divident b=divisor q=quotient r=remainder (a = qb + r)
def euclid(a,b):
    while True:
        q = 1       
        while max(a, b) - min(a, b) * (q + 1) > 0:
            q += 1
        else:
            r = max(a, b) - min(a, b) * q
            print('a = ', max(a, b), 'and b = ',min(a, b))
            euclid(r, min(a,b))
            
euclid(8, 3) 
print(1)
```

hi, i'm new to coding so it might be a dumb and obvious mistake that i unknowingly made.
I created a function to print the divident and divisor in every step of the euclidean algorithm for 8 and 3. However, i found out that the print(1) at the end doesn't seem to execute if i place it under the euclid() function. Additional information: if i change one of the numbers to 0 into my euclid function it doesn't work. Example: euclid(8,0)

Comment: Euclid never `return`s anything

Comment: @Colim He's not printing the return value, so that doesn't matter. The problem is that it never returns at all, it's stuck in both infinite looping and infinite recursion.

Comment: The whole `while max(a, b) - min(a, b) * (q + 1) > 0:  q += 1` part is actually a division...

Comment: You may be interested in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175131/code-for-greatest-common-divisor-in-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `euclid` begins with an infinite loop. However, you never stop iterating with a `break` or a `return` statement, therefore you are infinitely looping.

You are also infinitely recursing. Because `euclid` is calling itself and it never returns, the code never reaches your print statement.

This infinite recursion will cause a <del>Stack Overflow</del> Recursion error. This is because each time your function is called, the call is put on the stack. Since it never returns, the stack frame never gets destroyed.

**EDIT:**
The infinite recursion causes a Recursion error which is a safeguard against stack overflow by Python.

Comment: it will actually raise a `RecursionError`

Answer (score 0):

```
def euclid(a,b):
    while True:
        q = 1       
        while max(a, b) - min(a, b) * (q + 1) > 0:
            q += 1
        else:
            r = max(a, b) - min(a, b) * q
            if r == 0:
                break
            else:
                print('a = ', max(a, b), 'and b = ',min(a, b))
                euclid(r, min(a,b))
                return False
            
euclid(273, 100) 
print(1)
```

Added an `if` statement and a `break` to prevent infinite recursion ,
and a `return False` to prevent infinite looping. Thank you so much for taking time answering my question.